# Encryption data via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, encryption

I have a scenario where they have to pass data to Marketing Cloud via API, so I created an API call that allows me to insert records into a DE, in the following JSON:

```
{
   "items": [{
      "Nome":"Bobby",
      "Email" : "Jones@gmail.com",
      "SubKey": "23456"
   },
   {
      "Nome":"Sam",
      "Email" : "Sneed@gmail.com",
      "SubKey": "23476"
   }]
}
```

The client would like to have the Email Field as Encrypt Field.
How is it possible through the API call to pass this encrypted field to Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's no in-flight encryption/decryption of payload by the API. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_field_level_encryption.htm&type=5 <-- this is your best option out of the box. Educate your client on this.